# How to send data along with file in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am sending some data to server with one file, below is my code

```
val fileReqBody = pwdFile.asRequestBody("*/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pwdfile", pwdFile.name, fileReqBody)

        var registerDataService = RetrofitInstance.buildService(RegisterDataService::class.java)

        var call: Call<Object> = registerDataService.registerAccount(
            userName, email, firstName,
            lastName, srpSyncPass, deviceId,
            deviceType, deviceName, pubKey, part
        )

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Object> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Object>, response: Response<Object>) {
                Log.v("retrofit", call.toString() + ", " + response.body())

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Object>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.v("retrofit", "call failed")

            }

        })
```

My RegisterDataService code is below

```
interface RegisterDataService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("user/account/")
    fun registerAccount(@Part("username") username: String,
                        @Part("email") email: String,
                        @Part("firstname") firstName: String,
                        @Part("lastname") lastName: String,
                        @Part("srppass") srppass: String,
                        @Part("deviceid") deviceId: String,
                        @Part("devicetype") deviceType: Int,
                        @Part("devicename") deviceName: String,
                        @Part("pubkey") pubKey: String,
                        @Part pwdFile: MultipartBody.Part): Call<Object>

}
```

I am not getting proper result

But same thing in postman working fine
like below screenshot.

[image]

By postman it is working fine, can anyone help me where I am doing mistake?

File I am sending with Multipart.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have done by following way

```
val requestUserName = userName.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestEmail = email.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestFirstName = firstName.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestLastName = lastName.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestSyncPass = srpSyncPass.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestDeviceId = deviceId.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestDeviceName = deviceName.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val requestPubKey = pubKey.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

In RegisterDataService

```
@Multipart
    @POST("user/account/")
    fun registerAccount(@Part("username") username: RequestBody,
                        @Part("email") email: RequestBody,
                        @Part("firstname") firstName: RequestBody,
                        @Part("lastname") lastName: RequestBody,
                        @Part("srppass") srppass: RequestBody,
                        @Part("deviceid") deviceId: RequestBody,
                        @Part("devicetype") deviceType: Int,
                        @Part("devicename") deviceName: RequestBody,
                        @Part("pubkey") pubKey: RequestBody,
                        @Part pwdFile: MultipartBody.Part): Call<Object>
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
 @Multipart
   @POST("api/events/")
   Observable<Event> postEvent(

           @Part("name") RequestBody name,
           @Part("description") RequestBody description,    
   );

and request body,
 RequestBody requestBodyName = RequestBody.create(text, name);
 RequestBody requestBodyDescription = RequestBody.create(text, description);

then,
  return apiService.postEvent(requestBodyName,requestBodyDescription);
```